# What is wrong with this broken analog oscilloscope?

Tags: circuit-analysis, components, oscilloscope

I own an Hameg 204 analog oscilloscope.

Unfortunately the **x-axis oscillation on the CRT screen is broken**. I am looking for advice on how to fix this.

My background: I have fixed several little electronics devices. Examples include networks switch with burnt capacitors. This oscilloscope is much more complicated and a little above my level to handle it myself.

## Precise description of the issue

- Expected behavior: the CRT ray moves from the far left to the far right of the CRT screen.
- Actual behavior: the CRT ray is stuck at 60% of the x-axis of the screen (y-axis works fine). The x-pos button does nothing from 100 down to 50% and move the line start further right when turned from 50% to 0%.

  When I activate the "x magn x10" button, the ray moves from 60% to the far right.

  Basically, with the "x magn x10" trick, I have a working oscilloscope with only 40% of the original screen width. These "40%" do not depend on the time resolution.

## What I already did

The following was made with "x magn x10" always activated.

First thing I did what to get the schematics: http://www.sky-messtechnik.de/images/PDFs/HM204-1.pdf .

I made the hypothesis the issue comes from a faulty component in the 'x-final amplifier' (page 37 reproduced below).
[image: x-final amplifier]

I then used a working (digital) oscilloscope to check "from S281" point (it is not only 'from CT' as stated in the manual but also 'from timebase').
Here I see the x-oscillation I expected to see, with 0V in the middle (see image below). I can also confirm that x-pos (bottom left) works as intended (-12V to 0V).

"Inside" the x-final amplifier though, the situation is very different. I always see the same pattern (at both 'W2-6 CRT', Chp12, ...) but obviously with different voltages. depending on the location in the amplifier (see image below; minimum value is very close to 0V).

[image: Pattern seen on the working oscilloscope]

I do not see any weird-looking component (see picture).
[image: PCB picture of the x-final amplifier]

EDIT: I also checked all power rails and all are at their expected voltage.

## Where you can help

As the board is quite difficult to take apart (so I would like to do it only once), I am looking for some advice on how to precisely locate the faulty component so I can order a replacement.

I am hoping that for an experienced eye, the pattern would be typical of a specific component failure.

If needed, I can make further measurements.

## EDIT: new measurement:

T2101, base (to R2101):

[image: T2101]

T2101, collector (to R2110):

[image: T2101]

T2101, emitter (to R2100/R2101/R2108):

[image: T2101]

T2102, base (to R2103):

[image: T2102]

T2102, collector (to R2112):

[image]

T2102, emitter (to R2109, VR2100, VR2101):

[image]

Comment: Did you verify all Vdc , incl. 220Vdc?

Comment: Yes I did. +220,+12 and both -12V Vdc show no anomaly.

Comment: Compare Vb,Vc,Ve on T2101 and T2102. This is a differential output with single input with Xadj DC-offset and x10 gain and notice collector is inverted T2101 and non inverted on T2102 otherwise fault. The next stages are just differential buffers

Comment: Moving parts fail more often. Spray cleaner on variable resistors, switches & plugs and cycle them several times. If you must remove the board, reflow solder connections.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 : I have added the new measurements you suggested. I must admit I do not have enough knowledge to interpret them. (all made with x*10 on)

Comment: @Optionparty: I have checked the related switches and they seem to work fine. I have also checked variable resistors: turning the knob ha the intended effect (but no visible effect of the output)

Comment: Seems to be saturated on 2102 and not getting bias from -12V via R2133 bottom left.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 
Do you suggest T2102 has an issue? I really appreciate your help but while the next steps are probably obvious for you, it is a little difficult for me to follow. (With my computer science background, a transistor is no more than a relay in my functional view..., which clearly is not in this case in this circuit. So I am at loss here.)